# MemoryError with too large cursor in PyMongo with Pagination

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo

I have a cursor of objects that I'm trying Paginate. The total items I want is 25, but the way Pagination with Django works, it requires the *whole* cursor. In private testing, presumably because my home box has more RAM and the like, I do not have these issues. However, when pushing to the production machine, which has only 2GB of memory, I get a MemoryError, presumably because the cursor is too big.

I can use .limit(25) and .skip() in order to only retrieve 25 things at a time, however in order for Pagination to work, I need the total number of objects. Unfortunately, .count() seems to require getting the **entire data of the cursor**. Ideally, I can make this work if I can somehow get the size of a lookup and only 25 actual objects out of the cursor.

So I suppose the question is, is there a way to get a cursor's size that's not via .count() (which gets the whole cursor's data).

```
lookup = players.find({field: {'$exists': True}}).sort(field, DESCENDING)
//This returns a MemoryError

lookup = players.find({field: {'$exists': True}}).limit(25).skip(25).sort(field, DESCENDING)
//This does NOT return a Memory Error. However, when I do the following:

lookup.count()
//This also has a MemoryError.
```

For clarification, I am using Django 1.5.11 and pymongo 3.2.1.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `skip()` and `limit()` for pagination, it is usually recommended to use [range queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#query-for-ranges). This is because:

- `skip()` and `limit()` must iterate the cursor and throw away results, meaning you do a lot of unnecessary work.
- `skip()` and `limit()` cannot be supported by indexes.
- Range queries can be served very efficiently by indexes.

For example, instead of `skip()` and `limit()`, you can use a range of key. Using the `id` field as an example and assuming the `id` field is an increasing number:

```
db.collection.find({id: {$gte: 0, $lt: 25}, field: {'$exists': True}})
```

You then can create a [compound index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/index.html) of `id:1, field:1`, e.g.:

```
db.collection.createIndex({id:1, field:1})
```

This will make the pagination supported by an index so it's fast and efficient without doing any unnecessary work.

Comment: If my id field isn't in ascending order, how does that change the method above? I believe my document's current indices are randomly generated uuids, like `4321b5c5e4b0cad9a0f3e6a6` for example...

Comment: That was just an example. You would need to tailor the solution according to your schema and what data can be used to perform pagination.